# Javascript I want to use let img = new Image(); to display the image on browser

Tags: javascript, html

This is part of `html`.

```html
    <body>
        <canvas id='canvas' width="800" height="600" ></canvas>    
        <script src='test.js'></script>
    </body>
```

This is javascript file (test.js)

```js
    let cvs = document.getElementById('canvas');
    let ctx = cvs.getContext('2d');

    let bg = new Image();

    bg.src = 'earth.png';


    function draw(){

        ctx.drawImage(bg, 0, 0);

    }

    draw();
```

`earth.png` is not being shown on Chrome. I cannot find the mistake.

I use `vscode` to code this. I confirm that files `earth.png`, `test.js`, `test.html` are in the same folder.

And I use `vscode` extension `Live Server` to see what will be display in chrome.

Comment: You have to wait for the image to load before drawing it. Check out the onload property.

Comment: I found the same code can be run in some tutorial, why?

Comment: Maybe they used a data URI? I dunno. But you must wait for the image to load before drawing. See the examples here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`You cannot call the drawImage() method before the image has loaded.` - https://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_drawimage.asp

```js
let cvs = document.getElementById('canvas');
let ctx = cvs.getContext('2d');

let bg = new Image();

bg.src = 'earth.png';


function draw(){

    ctx.drawImage(bg, 0, 0);

}
bg.onload = draw;
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-nightingale-z1rrg